# Data annotation for Salutation

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

How can I add Data Annotation for Salutation?
A salutation must begin with Dear Sir or Madam, Mr, Mrs, Dr in lower or uppercase?

I tried the following but it not working for me:

`[RegularExpression(@"^(Dr|Mrs?|Ms)\. [A-Za-z] ([A - Za - z] (\s|\.|_)?)+[a-zA-Z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Greeting must begin with Mr., Mrs., Ms., or Dr")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this: `^(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr)\. [\p{L} '-]+$`. The assumption is that a surname can contain letters, not necessarily basic Latin (`\p{L}`), spaces in strict sense, apostrophes and hyphens. I did not add underscores. In the future you will probably need to extend this set.

This regular expression assumes that the salutation is all that is fed to to regular expression (i.e., that only salutation is subject to data annotation). If you check the whole letter, replace the final `$` with an `\n` (newline); and if there can be an address before the salutation, replace the initial `^` with `(?:^|\n)`. These newlines make sure that the salutation occupies a separate string. Do not use multiline option in this case.

Is the letter is user input, allow for extra spaces: `^\s*(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr)\.[ ]+[\p{L} '-]+$`.

Also, the full stop after the title can be missing, so: `^\s*(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr)\.? [ ]+[\p{L} '-]+$`.

You may want to add an optional final comma: `^\s*(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr)\.?[ ]+[\p{L} '-]+,?\s*$`.

Possible titles are also numerous, like `Prof.` or military ranks.